# Where can I find full documentation for the ArangoDB HTTP REST API?

Tags: rest, http, document, arangodb

The HTTP REST API documentation on the ArangoDB website looks incomplete. I need the full reference documentation so I can implement calls to ArangoDB's HTTP REST API from libcurl for C++.

Answer (score 1):

ArangoDB has Swagger UI, go to `Support` menu in `Admin`, then select `Rest API` tab

[image: ArangoDB Rest API Swagger UI]

You can also download `swagger.json` and generate `API clients and server stubs` via [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (for C++
is supported `cpprest`, `Qt5`, `Tizen`)